# Cut and delete a row in Apple Numbers in a single step

Tags: keyboard, numbers

In Apple Numbers, I think that I cut the content and deleted a row at the simultaneously in a single step. I did that by accident, but then I could not reproduce it. I have been searching but I cannot find any command.

I know I can:
- <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (cut the content of a row)
- Table > Delete Row (or go to the arrow on the left and Delete Row)

Can I do those two things in one step using the keyboard? 
This is something that I have to do many, many times and it would be very useful. Is it possible?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, you mean to keep the contents of the row in the clipboard and the delete. Or just delete the row disregarding the contents?

Comment: @bjbk: Cut the content and delete the row in one step. (Cut means keep the content in the clipboard but delete if from the existing row)

Comment: That’s what I thought you meant. Just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to duplicate your *Cut/Delete Row* with a single key combination but without creating an AppleScript I don't see a way.

However, as *Delete Row* is in the menu, one could make a custom keyboard shortcut to Delete the selected row after cutting the contents to the clipboard.

---

#### To create a shortcut specifically to delete a row in Numbers:

- Open ***System Preferences*** either from LaunchPad, the Dock or using Spotlight to find it.
- Select the *Keyboard* preferences
- Select the *Shortcuts* tab
- In the Left Pane select *App Shortcuts*
- Beneath the Right Pane click the Plus icon to add a shortcut [+]
- From the *Application* dropdown, select **Numbers**
- In the *Menu Tile* Type the menu command exactly as it appears in Numbers: `Delete Row`
- For the *Keyboard Shortcut* type the shortcut you wish to use taking care not to conflict with other shortcuts used in Numbers.  For example <kbd>option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Once this has been added, select your row, type <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to *Cut* the contents to the clipboard, then <kbd>option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to delete the row.  It requires the addition of one extra key stroke but will become second nature with muscle memory.

The demo below shows this method.  The contents are then pasted back showing they were cut to the clipboard before deleting the row.

---

[image: Custom shortcut for Numbers to delete row]

[image: Cutting contents of row then deleting the row]